# vaadin combobox defaultItem valueChangeListener

Tags: java, combobox, vaadin, vaadin7

i create a combobox for the read only modus with dropdown.

Here the part, where i create my combobox:

```
ComboBox createComboBox(String caption, List<String> items, String defaultItem) {
ComboBox comboBox = new ComboBox(caption, items);
comboBox.setWidth(width.getLength());
if (defaultValue != null) {
    comboBox.setValue(defaultValue);
}
comboBox.setNullSelectionAllowed(false);
comboBox.setTextInputAllowed(false);
```

Here the part, where i add the valueChangeListener:

```
comboBox.addValueChangeListener(valueChangeEvent -> 
comboBox.setValue(defaultValue));
```

when i dropdown the combobox and i select a value, i want to set the defaultvalue on change.

I have the problem, when the defaultItem is an empty string "", the selected item will be set as value.

Comment: It's not very clear what the issue is (perhaps `if (defaultValue != null && !defaultValue.trim().isEmpty())`?!). Can you please try to rephrase your question? Also why are you always setting the default value no matter what the user select in the combo?...

Comment: Where your code refers to `defaultValue`, should it instead be `defaultItem`? Do you first populate the comboBox with anything?